# Protobuf-net dynamictype array

Tags: object, serialization, protobuf-net, dynamictype

I wont to do some serialization with Protobuf-net and getting folowing error for this code snippet:

The error:

> Dynamic type is not a contract-type: TestType[]

The snippet:

```
using System.IO;
namespace QuickStart
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //FileAccess.ShowFileAccess();
            //Sockets.ShowSockets();

            var dto = new DataTransferType
            {
                ProtoDynamicProperty = new TestType[]
                {
                    new TestType {UselessProperty="AAA"},
                    new TestType{UselessProperty="BBB"},
                    new TestType{UselessProperty="CCC"}
                }
            };

            using (MemoryStream testStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ProtoBuf.Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(testStream, dto, ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle.Base128);
            }
        }


    }
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
    struct TestType
    {
        [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1)]
        public string UselessProperty { get; set; }
    }

    [ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
    class DataTransferType
    {
        [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, DynamicType = true)]
        public object ProtoDynamicProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this happens? I`m using 2.0.0.651 build

Comment: Having just answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39208449/protobuf-net-how-to-serialize-complex-collection/39214319#39214319) I realized I knew the answer to this old question also, so I went ahead and answered it, despite its age.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your difficulty is explained (albeit not fully) by the restrictions on `DynamicType` mentioned [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/protobuf-net/wikis/Attributes.wiki) at the [former project site](https://code.google.com/archive/p/protobuf-net/) for protobuf-net:

> `DynamicType` - stores additional `Type` information with the type (by default it includes the `AssemblyQualifiedName`, although this can be controlled by the user). This makes it possible to serialize weak models, i.e. where `object` is used for property members, however currently this is limited to **contract** types (not primitives), and does not work for types with inheritance (these limitations may be removed at a later time). Like with `AsReference`, this uses a very different layout format.

So, what *exactly* is meant by a **contract** type?  As stated, primitive types are not contract types, but is that all?  From [Protobuf-net: the unofficial manual: Forms of type serialization in protobuf-net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/642677/Protobuf-net-the-unofficial-manual#forms):

> I would say there are five fundamental kinds of [de]serialization that protobuf-net supports on a type-by-type basis (not including primitive types):
>
> 1. Normal serialization. In this mode, a standard protocol buffer is written, with one field in the protocol buffer for each field or property that you have marked with ProtoMember, or that has been auto-selected by ImplicitFields. ...
> 2. Collection serialization. If protobuf-net identifies a particular data type as a collection, it is serialized using this mode. Thankfully, collection types do not need any ProtoContract or ProtoMember attributes, which means you can serialize types such as List and T[] easily...
>
>    `<snip>`
>
>    Protobuf-net serializes a collection using a "repeated" field (in protocol buffer lingo). Therefore, you should be able to safely change collection types between versions. For example, you can serialize a Foo[] and later deserialize it into a List.

So serialization of a "contract type" corresponds to "normal serialization" in this article -- and collections are *not* contract types.  This explains the `Dynamic type is not a contract-type: TestType[]` exception message.

As a workaround, you can package your `ProtoDynamicProperty` inside a generic surrogate type that is guaranteed to correspond to a contract type and encapsulates the requisite type information, like so:

```
[ProtoContract]
public abstract class TypedObjectSurrogate
{
    protected TypedObjectSurrogate() { }

    [ProtoIgnore]
    public abstract object ObjectValue { get; }

    public static object CreateSurrogate<T>(T value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return new TypedObjectSurrogate<T>();
        var type = value.GetType();
        if (type == typeof(T))
            return new TypedObjectSurrogate<T>(value);
        // Return actual type of subclass
        return Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TypedObjectSurrogate<>).MakeGenericType(type), value);
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public sealed class TypedObjectSurrogate<T> : TypedObjectSurrogate
{
    public TypedObjectSurrogate() : base() { }

    public TypedObjectSurrogate(T value)
        : base()
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    [ProtoIgnore]
    public override object ObjectValue
    {
        get { return Value; }
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
class DataTransferType
{
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoIgnore]
    public object ProtoDynamicProperty { get; set; }

    [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, DynamicType = true)]
    object ProtoDynamicPropertySurrogate
    {
        get
        {
            if (ProtoDynamicProperty == null)
                return null;
            return TypedObjectSurrogate.CreateSurrogate(ProtoDynamicProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value is TypedObjectSurrogate)
                ProtoDynamicProperty = ((TypedObjectSurrogate)value).ObjectValue;
            else
                ProtoDynamicProperty = value;
        }
    }
}

[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
struct TestType
{
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1)]
    public string UselessProperty { get; set; }
}
```